# Calculate Relative Volume Ratio indicator in pandas data frame and add the indicator value as new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, technical-indicator

I know there have been a few posts on this, but my case is a little bit different and I wanted to get some help on this.

I have a pandas dataframe symbol_df with 1 min bars in the below format for each stock symbol:

```
id  Symbol_id                Date     Open     High      Low    Close  Volume
1          1 2023-12-13 09:15:00  4730.95  4744.00  4713.95  4696.40    2300
2          1 2023-12-13 09:16:00  4713.20  4723.70  4717.85  4702.55    1522
3          1 2023-12-13 09:17:00  4716.40  4718.55  4701.00  4701.00     909
4          1 2023-12-13 09:18:00  4700.15  4702.80  4696.70  4696.00     715
5          1 2023-12-13 09:19:00  4696.70  4709.90  4702.00  4696.10     895
...        ...                 ...      ...      ...      ...      ...     ...
108001     1 2024-03-27 13:44:00  6289.95  6291.95  6289.00  6287.55     989
108002     1 2024-03-27 13:45:00  6288.95  6290.85  6289.00  6287.75     286
108003     1 2024-03-27 13:46:00  6291.25  6293.60  6292.05  6289.10    1433
108004     1 2024-03-27 13:47:00  6295.00  6299.00  6293.20  6293.15    2702
108005     1 2024-03-27 13:48:00  6292.05  6296.55  6291.95  6291.95     983
```

I would like to calculate the "Relative Volume Ratio" indicator and add this calculated value to the symbol_df as a new column on a rolling basis.

"Relative volume ratio" indicator calculated as below:

So far today's Volume is compared with the mean volume of the last 10 days of the same period. To get the ratio value, we simply divide "today so far volume"  by "mean volume of the last 10 days of the same period".

For example..the current bar time is now 13:48.

`cumulativeVolumeOfToday = Volume` of 1 minuite bars between 00:00 -13:48 today added up

`avergeVolumeOfPreviousDaysOfSamePeriod = Average` accumulation of volume from the same period(00:00 - 13:48) over the last 10 days.

```
relativeVolumeRatio = CumulativeVolumeOfToday/AvergeVolumeOfPrevious10DaysOfSamePeriod
```

Add this value as a new column to the dataframe.

Sample data download for the test case:

```
import yfinance as yf #pip install yfinance
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

symbol_df = yf.download(tickers="AAPL", period="7d", interval="1m")["Volume"] 
symbol_df=symbol_df.reset_index(inplace=False)
#symbol_df['Datetime'] = symbol_df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
symbol_df = symbol_df.rename(columns={'Datetime': 'Date'})
#We can only download 7 days sample data. So 5 days mean for calculations
```

How can I do this in Pandas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 1) I think there's no need to transform date-time stamp into a string. On the contrary, you have more opportunities to manipulate data with the `datetime` type. 2) Let's say you have data for March 20, 21, 22, 25 of this year (March 23 and 24, i.e. a weekend, are skipped). How would you define "previous 3 days of March 25th"? Will it be 20, 21, 22 or 22, 23, 24?

Comment: My original data is stored in SQLite db with epoch format with different time zones. I am doing a few transformations to the data frame along the way and got to this stage. I agree that the "datetime" type format is better and my string formatting can be ignored. Only added this conversion to match my original example. True, only weekdays should be considered and weekend days should be skipped. ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

```
from yfinance import download

# Prepare data similar to the original
symbol_df = (
    download(tickers="AAPL", period="7d", interval="1m")
    .rename_axis(index='Date')
    .reset_index()
)

# Calculate Relative Volume Ratio
volume = symbol_df.set_index('Date')['Volume']
dts = volume.index
cum_volume = volume.groupby(dts.date, sort=False).cumsum()
prev_mean = lambda days: (
    cum_volume
    .groupby(dts.time, sort=False)
    .rolling(days, closed='left')
    .mean()
    .reset_index(0, drop=True)    # drop the level with dts.time
)
rvr = cum_volume / prev_mean(5)

# Assign the output to the initial data
symbol_df = symbol_df.join(rvr.rename('Relative volume ratio'), on='Date')
```

#### Explanation

Based on the provided description, you need to perform several transformations on the aggregated data. First is to cumulatively summarize the data for each day. Then run a [ten]-day window over the data grouped by time of day to calculate the average. And at the end, actually divide the former by the latter.

Let's say, you have the following test data, where `"Date"` is a column of type `datetime`:

```
from yfinance import download

symbol_df = (
    download(tickers="AAPL", period="7d", interval="1m")
    .rename_axis(index='Date')
    .reset_index()
)
```

To calculate the *Relative Volume Ratio* values, we will use `"Volume"` as a separate sequence with date-time stamps `"Date"` as its index:

```
volume = symbol_df.set_index('Date')['Volume']
dts = volume.index    # date-time stamps for convenient grouping
```

Let's create a sequence of cumulative volumes for each day. For this, we group `volume` by its date (the year, month and day values with no time) and apply `cumsum` to a group (use `sort=False` in hopes to speed up calculations):

```
cum_volume = volume.groupby(dts.date, sort=False).cumsum()
```

To calculate the mean of cumulative volumes at the same time of day in the given number of previous days, we group `cum_volume` by its time (hours and minutes with no year, month, day values), and apply rolling calculations to each group to obtain averages over windows. *Note that here we need the source data to be sorted by date-time stamps since only business days are taken into account and we can't use a non-fixed frequency of `"10B"` as a `window` value.* To calculate means for exactly the previous days excluding the current one, we pass `closed='left'` (see [DataFrameGroupBy.rolling docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.rolling.html) for details):

```
prev_mean = lambda days: (
    cum_volume
    .groupby(dts.time, sort=False)
    .rolling(days, closed='left')
    .mean()
    .reset_index(0, drop=True)
)
```

Now the final touch with the window of 5 days:

```
rvr = cum_volume / prev_mean(5)
```

#### Comparison

Compared to [Andrei Kesely's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78235015/14909621), this one wins in speed (on Intel Core i3-2100, for example, processing the data offered there will take over 1 minute versus 300-400 ms with the code above). The calculation result is the same for timestamps after the first 10 days. But in the beginning, when there's less then 10 previous days, calculation of mean in rolling windows is made as if there's always 10 items (missing values are set to nan). Whereas in the case of the Kesely's solution, we obtain average values only for the *available* cumulative volumes.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post to get a sample data frame but only contains 7 days data. So mean value calculation is needed for 5 days. I am still trying to digest your logic but the code is erroring. It appears your logic is faster. Can you please help? Appreciated.

Comment: Cheers, Thanks so much for the answer!  I was trying similar logic by going through pandas docs.. filtering the frame rows by grouping by time & cum_volume then trying to calculate the mean but I was brain fogged and didn't get that far. Your solution is very elegant. It executed very fast and "rvr" values are calculated but I was trying to add these cum_volume, prev_mean, rvr as new columns to my "symbol_df" frame but showing as 'NaN'.. what I am missing?

Comment: @user23791331 If the computed values are not all NaN at once, you might just be assigning objects, ignoring the difference in their indices. As you can see, I used `symbol_df.join` to add the result, rather than `symbol_df['new column'] = rvr`. You could try `... = rvr.reset_index(drop=True)` or `... = rvr.values`, but some calculations can reorder the records. So you may get the resulting data in the wrong places after a direct assignment. Using `merge` or `join` is safer in this sense.

Comment: @user23791331 In other words `symbol_df['new column'] = rvr` is not a regular assignment, but _LEFT JOIN_ on  index. If `symbol_df` and `rvr` have different indexes, you will see nans in a new column.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's working like magic! I could apply same logic to calculate other aggregate functions I have in pipeline. Learnt few new things with pandas.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question right:

1. compute cumulative sum of "Volume" for today (that is, from 00:00 to current datetime)
2. compute mean of sums of Volumes for last 10 days from 00:00 to time (derived from current time)
3. divide the cumulative sum of "Volume" for today with the mean of sums from last 10 days

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


df = df.set_index("Date")


cache = {}


def get_volume_sum(df, dt):
    rv = cache.get(dt, None)
    if rv is None:
        rv = df.loc[dt.date() : dt, "Volume"].sum()
        cache[dt] = rv
    return rv


out, N = [], 10
for d in tqdm(df.index):
    cumulativeVolumeOfToday = get_volume_sum(df, d)
    vals = []
    for day in range(N, 0, -1):
        dt = d - pd.Timedelta(days=day)
        vals.append(get_volume_sum(df, dt))
    if not vals:
        out.append(np.nan)
    else:
        AvergeVolumeOfPrevious10DaysOfSamePeriod = np.mean(np.array(vals))
        if AvergeVolumeOfPrevious10DaysOfSamePeriod != 0:
            out.append(
                cumulativeVolumeOfToday / AvergeVolumeOfPrevious10DaysOfSamePeriod
            )
        else:
            out.append(np.nan)

df["relativeVolumeRatio"] = out
print(df.tail(10))
```

Prints (the computation took ~21 seconds for 150k of records on my machine AMD 5700x):

```py
100%|███████████████████████████████████| 151474/151474 [00:21<00:00, 7136.78it/s]

                     Symbol_id  Open  Close  Volume  relativeVolumeRatio
Date                                                                    
2024-03-27 13:39:00          1  3520   4340     731             0.993289
2024-03-27 13:40:00          1  4868   4748     131             0.992341
2024-03-27 13:41:00          1  5833   5342    1828             0.992327
2024-03-27 13:42:00          1  4006   3419    1755             0.992667
2024-03-27 13:43:00          1  3465   3827     690             0.992588
2024-03-27 13:44:00          1  5624   4924    2315             0.993013
2024-03-27 13:45:00          1  5012   5321    2961             0.993927
2024-03-27 13:46:00          1  3292   4193     112             0.992635
2024-03-27 13:47:00          1  4823   5520    2098             0.993061
2024-03-27 13:48:00          1  4937   4560     679             0.992526
```

---

The dataframe was created with:

```py
np.random.seed(42)


def generate_df(from_, to_):
    dr = pd.date_range(from_, to_, freq="1min")
    return pd.DataFrame(
        {
            "Symbol_id": [1] * len(dr),
            "Date": dr,
            "Open": np.random.randint(3000, 6000, size=len(dr)),
            "Close": np.random.randint(3000, 6000, size=len(dr)),
            "Volume": np.random.randint(100, 3000, size=len(dr)),
        }
    )


df = generate_df("2023-12-13 09:15:00", "2024-03-27 13:48:00")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer.  Yes, you got the question right. I need to apply this solution to a 200 symbols data frame. Each symbol_df will contain approximately 100k records and every 1 minute a new row will be added to each data frame. So 2 mins is too high and this solution will be slow for my requirements.  Thanks again.

Comment: Well, it took 6 minutes in case of Intel Core i3-2100. IMO you're duplicating too many operations.

Comment: @Vitalizzare Yes, you're right - I've added caching, now it completes in 21 seconds (instead 2 minutes)

Comment: @user23791331 I've added caching, now it should complete faster.